# SATA Disk not recognized in brand new server

Tags: hard-drive, hp, sata, hp-proliant

We bought a HP Proliant ml350 g6 server for our work place. It comes with RAID 5 supportted by SAS disks. It also has SATA 750 GB disk.

We wanted to install windows server 2008, but the SATA disk is not detected. I thought it was a driver issue and installed the OS on the SAS disk. But even after installing the driver for SATA controller, the SATA disk is not detected.

I even tried a diferent slot for the SATA disk, but in vain.

Has this got anything to do with the BIOS settings. I see that all the SATA PCI have IRQ as 10. Should I change the IRQ's ? I think the DVD drive is also SATA.

I have given all the info I know. Please help me out. I am dejected with this.

Comment: Have you tried connecting a known-good SATA drive to the controller and see if the server recognizes that drive?  If so, you probably have a bad SATA drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the array configuration utility in the boot loader to create a logical disk worked. With this the SATA disk was detected.

Comment: ah sorry, didn't think of that one, assumed you'd dealt with that, sorry for not starting with such an easy one. C.

Comment: And where/how can you find the array configuration in the boot loader please?

Answer (score 1):

What if you boot a linux LiveCD like the bootable Ubuntu CD? Does that see the drives on the controller? That could help narrow down if it's a drive/controller issue or a problem with a driver.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the disk or SATA cables - I know the P410i controller in that machine well and have connected a number of disks from a variety of manufacturers without issue - try another drive or this suspect drive in another machine if possible.